# Cs50 Pset4. Resize More. Cant figure out how to make it smaller

Tags: c, cs50

I figured out how to make an image bigger, but for the life of me I cant figure out how to make it smaller. The current code will make a bitmap the right size but fill it with random colors. The current code makes sense to me, i think the problem might be with the headers or the padding. Please Help!
[Original vs output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkxzC.jpg)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "bmp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./resize f infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* GET FACTOR */
    float f = atof( argv[1]);
    if (f < 0.0 || f > 100.0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "The factor is out of bounds\n");
        return 5;
    }

    //check if we are making it bigger
    bool big = true;
    int factor = 0;
    if ( f <= 1.0)
    {
        big = false;
        factor = floor(1/f);
    }
    else
    {
        big = true;
        factor = floor(f);
    }
    /**/

    // remember filenames
    char *infile = argv[2];
    char *outfile = argv[3];

    // open input file
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 2;
    }

    // open output file
    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
        return 3;
    }

    // read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf, bfn;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);
    bfn=bf;

    // read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi,bin;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);
    bin=bi;

    // ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 4;
    }

    /*Original pad*/
    int oldpadding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;
    /**/

    /*CHANGE THE INFOHEADER W&H SIZE*/
    bin.biWidth= floor(bi.biWidth * f);
    bin.biHeight= floor(bi.biHeight * f);

     /*NEW PADDING*/
     int padding = (4 - (bin.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;
    /*GET NEW SIZE*/
    bin.biSizeImage = ((sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) * bin.biWidth) + padding) * abs(bin.biHeight);
    bfn.bfSize = bin.biSizeImage + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    /**/




    // write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    fwrite(&bfn, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    fwrite(&bin, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);



    if(big)
    {
        // iterate over infile's scanlines
       for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
        {

            for(int w = 0; w < factor; w++)
            {
                // temporary storage
                RGBTRIPLE triple;


                // iterate over pixels in scanline
                for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
                {
                    // read RGB triple from infile
                    fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

                    for(int x = 0 ; x < factor ; x++)
                    {
                        // write RGB triple to outfile
                        fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
                    }

                }
                for (int k = 0; k < padding; k++)
                {
                    fputc(0x00, outptr);
                }
                fseek(inptr, -1*sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)*bi.biWidth, SEEK_CUR);
            }
            // skip over padding, if any
            fseek(inptr, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)*bi.biWidth+oldpadding, SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
        {
            // iterate over pixels in scanline
            for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
            {
                // temporary storage
                RGBTRIPLE triple;

                // read RGB triple from infile
                fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);
                if(i%factor==0&&j%factor==0)
                {

                    // write RGB triple to outfile
                    fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
                }
            }

            // skip over padding, if any
            fseek(inptr, oldpadding, SEEK_CUR);

            // then add it back (to demonstrate how)
            for (int k = 0; k < padding; k++)
            {
                fputc(0x00, outptr);
            }
        }
    }

    // close infile
    fclose(inptr);

    // close outfile
    fclose(outptr);

    // success
    return 0;
}
`
```

Comment: Have you checked what factor is after this line? `factor = floor(1/f);` That's integer division, so it's almost certainly zero. If you're going to sample every 2 or 3 or 4 pixels, you want your factor to be 2,3,4j just like when you're making it larger, but instead of writing N pixels per source pixel you ignore N source pixels between samples and writes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, that line works, for instance, f=0.25 will return 4

Comment: You're right, I didn't see that f was a float. Since I don't know what your source image or dest image look like it's hard to guess at the issue.  If you have a padding problem the first line will be right and then each line after will be offset by some amount, and if it isn't an even amount the colors will shift too. Try a bmp with a white background and vertical black stripes. That would make a padding issue very obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I found with your code was that iterating over the source width/height and trying to read/write as you go would end up writing more data than it should, and potentially getting the file pointers out of sync.

As an example, with a 512x512 source image and a factor of 3 you end up writing extra pixels per line, both because 512 * 0.33 is not the same as 512 / 3, and 512 % 3 != 0;

The way I would normally do it is to load the data into memory and iterate over the destination width/height assigning the proper pixels from the source.

I don't have bmp.h so I included Windows.h instead, and I switched to opening the files in binary mode, since you don't want any line endings getting translated. I'm also compiling in C++ mode, so there's a few casts you may not need if you're compiling as C.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float f = 0.33f;
    int factor = 1 / f;
    FILE *inptr = fopen("infile.bmp", "rb");
    FILE *outptr = fopen("outfile.bmp", "wb");

    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf, bfn;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);
    bfn = bf;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi, bin;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);
    bin = bi;

    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 || bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 4;
    }

    bin.biWidth *= f;
    bin.biHeight *= f;
    int srcStride = (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) + 3) & ~3;
    int dstStride = (bin.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) + 3) & ~3;

    bin.biSizeImage = dstStride * abs(bin.biHeight);
    bfn.bfSize = bin.biSizeImage + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    fwrite(&bfn, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);
    fwrite(&bin, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

    char* srcData = (char*)calloc(1, bi.biSizeImage);
    fread(srcData, bi.biSizeImage, 1, inptr);
    char* dstData = (char*)calloc(1, bin.biSizeImage);

    for (int i = 0, binHeight = abs(bin.biHeight); i < binHeight; i++)
    {
        RGBTRIPLE* src = (RGBTRIPLE*)&srcData[srcStride * i * factor];
        RGBTRIPLE* dst = (RGBTRIPLE*)&dstData[dstStride * i];
        for (int j = 0; j < bin.biWidth; j++)
        {
            dst[j] = src[j * factor];
        }
    }
    fwrite(dstData, bin.biSizeImage, 1, outptr);
    fclose(inptr);
    fclose(outptr);
    free(srcData);
    free(dstData);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Retired Ninja, I’ll give it a shot when I get home!